# Show the slots as Today and Tomorrow for E-commerce based on client current time

Tags: angularjs

I am getting an array as from factories, service in controller.

```
$scope.getallslots=SlotService.getslots();
```

In this array i am having data as.
[image]

Now I want to compare the current time and existing time from the array. And based on the time i want to show my data.
I have converted the current time to ISO string format as per database but, i want to check only time but not date. Any help, will helpful.

Comment: your object has from and to date , which date you will be using for the logic to check the slot falls under today or tomorrow.

Comment: Its not date, its timing. Like from 9 AM to 11 AM, 12 PM to 2 PM... and I will check the from time to get slots.

Comment: Could you explain a little more , if these are only time slots(since you dont want to consider the date and only time )  then how will you decide which is today and which is tomorrow

Comment: Just for understanding i have given two objects but i have a number of slots dear.

Answer (score 1):

Guys I got the answer.

1. Convert the date in time format at admin side and store only time in the 
   MongoDB using the timepicker or date.
2. Now take two different ng-model and check the condition as per need
3. Later get that date at client side and check with the current time format.
4. after checkin push those value one by one in the ng-model which is array.

Now it's done. Here is example, Its at server side,

```
$scope.Delivary.from=$filter("date")($scope.Delivary.from,'shortTime')
$scope.Delivary.to=$filter("date")($scope.Delivary.to,'shortTime')
```

The above code should be written before pushing/saving the slots at admin panel

Here is example, Its at client side

```
$scope.slotupdatedlist=[]-->1st ng-model
$scope.slotupdatedlist1=[]-->2nd ng-model

$scope.gettime=CartListService.getslots().$promise.then(function(data){
    angular.forEach(data,function(list){
        console.log(list)
        var currtime=new Date();
          $scope.HHmmss = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'HH:mm');


    if(((list.from<$scope.HHmmss) && (list.to>$scope.HHmmss))||((list.to<$scope.HHmmss))){//checking condition

        $scope.slotupdatedlist1.push(list);
    }
        else{
            $scope.slotupdatedlist.push(list);
            console.log($scope.HHmmss)
        }

    })


})
```

Now assign those ng-model in your HTML page and you can get the Slots

```
<h4>Available Slots</h4>
<span>Today</span><br>
<label class="checkbox-entry radio" ng-repeat="slot in slotupdatedlist">
<input type="radio" name="custom-name"><span class="check"></span>
{{slot.from}} -- {{slot.to}}<br>
</label>
 <span>Tomorrow</span><br>
 <label class="checkbox-entry radio" ng-repeat="slot in slotupdatedlist1">
 <input type="radio" name="custom-name"><span class="check"></span>
  {{slot.from}} -- {{slot.to}}<br>
  </label>
```

Comment: Really Thanks @Nitin Agarwal. Its saved my time with this.